# React Hooks useState promptly Update

Tags: react-hooks

How can I promptly update the number state and watch `console.log(number)` updated value?

```
    const [number,setNumber] = useState(0);
    const minus = () => {
      setNumber(number-1);
      console.log(number);
    }
    return (
     <>
      <div>{number}</div>
      <button onClick={minus}>-</button>
     </>
    )
```

Comment: your code looks fine. Are u not getting the expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a side-effect: print something onto the console.

This is what `useEffect` hook is for - it lets you perform side effects.

So here is a possible implementation:

```
function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const minus = () => {
    setNumber(number - 1);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(number);
  }, [number]);
  return (
    <>
      <div>{number}</div>
      <button onClick={minus}>-</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Of course, it may be an overkill solution if you are just using `console.log` for debugging purpose. If that's the case, @zynkn and @deepak-k's answers work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 setNumber((number)=> {number-1 ; console.log(number)});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [number,setNumber] = useState(0);
    const minus = () => {
      // setNumber(number-1);  
      // It is also work well but it is working with async. 
      // So you can't see the below console.log().
      // console.log(number);
      setNumber((prevNumber) => {
        newNumber = prevNumber - 1;
        console.log(newNumber);
        return newNumber;
      });
    }

    return (
     <>
      <div>{number}</div>
      <button onClick={minus}>-</button>
     </>


)
```